# Как сделать меню, чтобы главная категория меню кликалась на Bootstrap для WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

Сделал [вот так](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker), потом добавил выпадание при наведении. Проблема в том, что теперь вид:

```
--О нас
---История
---Клиенты
```

При нажатии на `О нас` ссылка пропадает и никуда не переходит, а только открывается подменю.
В стандартном наборе без Bootstrap все переходит. Как сделать, что бы был переход?